# Floating asp:buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am implementing a search where in I have 10 fields and 4 buttons and the page renders absolutely perfect for me.
I have provided the option of Advanced Search for the user, where the user clicks on a link and the panel expands ( I am just using the toggle functionality here).

The problem comes here because of the vertical scroll, the buttons are not visible straight away, I have to scroll down to see those..so my idea is to make those buttons float..Can you please suggest me how can I implement that..or any alternate idea to achieve the above functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "asp:buttons" only exist in the imagination of the .NET framework. Show us the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating your button, you can put the button inside a div.
 Then put the Advanced search controls in another div that scrolls.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="overflow:auto; height:300px; vertical-align:top;">
                <table height="500">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3>Advanced Search controls here in this div</h3></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:right; padding-top:20px;">
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="buttonSearch" Text="Search" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This way the Search button stays fixed.

If you don't want to scroll to see all the options you can implement a floating button.

See this: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html
You'll have to put your Search button in a div. Then position it near your controls in your Update Panel.

Here's a related question that may help.
[ASP.NET Floating Div Menu via Ajax or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836486/asp-net-floating-div-menu-via-ajax-or-jquery)

Comment: No but that doesn't sound that good right, scrolling the div to view what are all the options available?

Comment: Try the link I've added above. Add your button to a div and float the div.